# HTTP POST from website

Tags: json, rest, api, post

I'm trying to send a rest api HTTP POST job from a website, but can't figure out how to do it.

I have tryed from a Restlet clien and that works fine.

Can anyone here please help me?

Method: POST
Host: https://example.com
Headers: 
        Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxmykeyxxxxxxxx
        Content-Type:  application/json
Body: {
    "callerLookup" : { "email" : "usr@dom.com" },
    "status": "secondLine",
    "request": "Dette er en test\n af afsendelse af en outogenereret sag.",
    "category":{
        "name": "IT"
    },
    "briefDescription" : "Test"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JavaScript:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://example.com', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxmykeyxxxxxxxx');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', ' application/json');
xhr.send('yourBody');
```

Comment: Nice, thank you very much, this is working perfectly